# What is the regular expression for validating jabber id?

Tags: regex, validation, xmpp

For now I'm using this regexp:

```
^\A([a-z0-9\.\-_\+]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z$
```

I think it is not very good. So what's the best regular expression you have or have seen for validating jids?

For reference, [Section 3 of the XMPP core standard](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html#addressing) defines a JID in Augmented Backus-Naur Form as

```
jid             = [ node "@" ] domain [ "/" resource ]
domain          = fqdn / address-literal
fqdn            = (sub-domain 1*("." sub-domain))
sub-domain      = (internationalized domain label)
address-literal = IPv4address / IPv6address
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the rules that constitute a legal jabber id.

Comment: ire_and_curses already fixed my oversight, thanks.

Comment: I don't think you realize how much you're asking.  This task is very similar to validating an email address, which is very, very complicated and not well suited to regexes.  Check this out: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Another issue with your regex is it doesn't take into account the large number of Unicode code points that are legal in JIDs, but are not a-z0-9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regexp is wrong at least in the following points:

1. It requires jid to contain a '@', though jids without a '@' may also be valid.
2. It doesn't check the maximal length (but the link you provided says "Each allowable portion of a JID MUST NOT be more than 1023 bytes in length")

I think having one huge regexp is a wrong way to go. You'd better write some more code, splitting the jid into smaller parts (domain, node, resource) and then checking each of those parts. That would be better from multiple points:

- easier testing (you can unit test each of the parts independently)
- better performance
- simpler code
- reusability
- etc.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
^(?:([^@/<>'\"]+)@)?([^@/<>'\"]+)(?:/([^<>'\"]*))?$
```

It's not *quite* right, since there are lots of things that match it that aren't valid JIDs, particularly in the domain name portion.  However, it should allow and parse all *valid* JIDs, with group 1 being the node, group 2 being the domain, and group 3 being the resource.

---

Test Data:

```
foo                 (None,  'foo', None)
foo@example.com     ('foo', 'example.com', None)
foo@example.com/bar ('foo', 'example.com', 'bar')
example.com/bar     (None,  'example.com', 'bar')
example.com/bar@baz (None,  'example.com', 'bar@baz')
example.com/bar/baz (None,  'example.com', 'bar/baz')
bär@exämple.com/bäz ('bär', 'exämple.com', 'bäz')
```

---

Aside: if you aren't familiar with the construct (?:), it's a set of parens that doesn't add a group to the output.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick search, see:

http://jdconley.com/blog/archive/2007/03/13/validating-jabberid-nodes-xmppsoapbox-user-names.aspx